# Mixing @client fragment with remote fragment doesn't work

Tags: graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I use ApolloClient 3 and webpack's `graphql-tag/loader`. The beginning of my file looks like:

```
#import '../../hooks/fragments/User/basicUserInfo.gql'

fragment IsLeftSidebarOpen on Query {
  isLeftSidebarOpen @client
}
```

These 3 following snippets are in the same file that `IsLeftSidebarOpen` fragment is. Of course I test them one by one by changing file, not all at once.
 Could you explain me why

a) this works

```
query FetchData {
  me {
    ...BasicUserInfo
  }
  isLeftSidebarOpen @client
}
```

b) this also works

```
query FetchData {
  ...IsLeftSidebarOpen @client
}
```

c) but this throws the following error `Unknown fragment "IsLeftSidebarOpen"`

```
query FetchData {
  me {
    ...BasicUserInfo
  }
  ...IsLeftSidebarOpen @client
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from your question where `IsLeftSidebarOpen` is defined and how you are importing it. Also, if you're using the graphql-tag loader, that should be mentioned.

Comment: @DanielRearden sorry, I've just edited my question

Comment: @TomaszSuperson Did you solve the issue? I’m running into the same problem...